# Default dialer issue

Tags: phone-app

I am using samsung S3 and installed Truecaller on this, now when i make a call from truecaller, the options shown in the popup are only the default dialer and Skype, not truecaller. I have cleared all defaults and tried it with multiple dialer apps, but everytime I see only these two options for dialing out. Any idea on how i can use truecaller for dialing out?
Thanks
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

That's the way it should work. Truecaller just provides a dailer. It is not a *call handling* application. The main motto of the Truecaller dailer is to show info of the number before a call is placed.

Comment: Thanks Mani. I installed exdialer and the result is same. I restored default factory settings on my phone 1 month back, prior to that this was working fine with me getting exdialer as option.